# FancyBox - Незакрываемый iFrame

Tags: fancybox

Всем Доброго времени суток. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой.
На странице, с помощью *fancybox* я разместил презентацию *Google Docs*. Всё работает хорошо, но мне очень не нравится, что при загрузке страницы, она автоматически загружается. Как можно убрать автозагрузку *iFrame*? Потратил много времени для решения данной проблемы, но к сожалению ничего не помогло.
*FancyBox* версии 2.1.1. Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Напишите код как вы разместили презентацию, а то в экстрасенсов играть не очень хочется :)

Comment: В том то и дело, что всё чрезвычайно просто. И так, вот ссылка содержащая адрес презентации <a id="tour" class="fancybox.iframe" href="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zNO2ALcN42t_46TQ7AZRAKeiMkFi7dluE1xJaDNa2cY/embed?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000">Тур по сайту!</a> после, идут подключения библиотек <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script> в файле script.js находится скрипт запускающий презентацию по щелчку на ссылке, в данный момент пустой

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7905/deleted, тег <pre></pre> для кода не используйте где попала

Comment: @СергейКашурин перенесите Ваш код в текст вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Ответ был прост, жаль что столько времени потратил. У кого такая же проблема, ответ вот:
    $('#tour').removeClass(".fancybox.iframe");

```
$("#tour").live("click", function(e) {
$("#tour").addClass(".fancybox.iframe");

$('#tour').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 746,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '80%',
        height      : '80%',
        padding     : 0,
        afterShow   : false
    });
e.preventDefault(); 
});
Просто удалите вначале классы которые нужны fancybox, а потом при клике по ссылке добавьте, и не забудьте e.preventDefault(); иначе перейдёте по ссылке.
```